# Mixing System.Transactions with SqlTransactions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I've been brushing up on my knowledge this evening, trying to overcome 4 years of bad programming practices because of the company I was working for. One of the things I've recently stumbled on was System.Transactions. After reading about them for the last few hours, I think I have an adequate understanding of how they work and why you would want to use them. However, all the examples I've looked at are showing inline T-SQL being called from within the transaction.

I pretty much use Stored Procedures exclusively when doing database access and the existing stored procedures are all wrapped in their own SqlTransactions. You know, using 'Begin Tran' and then rolling back or committing. If a Stored Proc calls another stored proc, it too creates a transaction and the Commits bubble up until the outer one either commits or rolls back. Works great.

So now my question is, if I wanted to start using System.Transactions in my code - for the simple purposes of monitoring successive database tasks that can't be nested inside a single Stored Procedure - how does that work with the existing SqlTransactions I already have in my stored procs?

Will using System.Transactions in my code just add one more layer of protection before it is actually committed, or because I'm explicitly committing in my SqlTransaction - will the data be persisted regardless of committing or rolling back in code based transaction?

Comment: The accepted answer on this question is wrong. Using a Sql transaction within a System.Transaction causes unintended behavior (namely, a Sql transaction does NOT participate on the outer System.Transaction!) Doing this effectively neutralizes your transaction.

Comment: Thanks for following up to make these corrections, Bill. 7 years later and I can't even remember if I ended up implementing anything that needed this, but it's good to have the correct answer marked. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, System.Transactions and Sql transactions do not mix.**

And I quote, "Do Not Mix Them" from the following MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx.

Sql transactions do not participate on the outer System.Transaction the way you want them to. Sql transactions that fail or rollback will not cause other activities within the System.Transaction to rollback.

---

This example shows the phenomena:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection($"{connectionstring}"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var com = new SqlCommand($"set xact_abort on; begin transaction; INSERT INTO dbo.KeyValueTable VALUES ('value1', '{Guid.NewGuid()}'); rollback;", con))
        {
            // This transaction failed, but it doesn't rollback the entire system.transaction!
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (var com = new SqlCommand($"set xact_abort on; begin transaction; INSERT INTO dbo.KeyValueTable VALUES ('value2', '{Guid.NewGuid()}'); commit;", con))
        {
            // This transaction will actually persist!
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    tx.Complete();
}
```

After running this example on an empty data store you should notice that the records from the second Sql operation are indeed committed, when the structure of the C# code would imply that they shouldn't be.

---

Put simply, you should not mix them. If you are orchestrating multiple Sql transactions within an application you should just use System.Transactions. Unfortunately that would mean removing your transaction code from all of your stored procedures, but alas, it is necessary as with a mixed model you cannot guarantee the integrity of your data.

Comment: What if the an explicit ADO.Net transaction were used for the SqlCommand and that transaction were enlisted into the XA transaction (or is that even possible)?  Would that cancel the XA transaction?

Answer (score -1):

Works just fine, if your inner transactions within the stored procs are committed everything will commit. If one of them roll back then everything within the outer transcation will roll back. Pure magic. :)

Comment: Excellent. That's what I was hoping for and it seemed like the logical answer, I just didn't want to assume. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is definitively wrong. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx

Comment: Accepted answer has been changed. :)